# php/html - logic for drop down menu and pagination

Tags: php, html, pagination

I am having a bit of trouble going through the logic of changing how many images I want to have displayed.

1. Can't select the 1st option (5).
2. Selected option is always at 10. (Probably has to do with the if statement) The idea of the if statement is to default a value upon 1st displaying the page. I have tried the selected attribute, but that doesn't work since the form is an on-change event.
3. Lastly, the pagination bug: If I successfully change the code to correctly display the amount of images, the pagination links will mess up.

```html
  echo '<form method="post">
    <select name="displayAmount" onchange="this.form.submit();">
        <option>5</option>
        <option>10</option>
        <option>15</option>
        <option>20</option>
        <option>25</option>
    </select>';
    
if (isset($_GET['$selected'])) {
   $selected = $_POST['displayAmount'];
  } else {
   $selected = 10;
  }
  

  echo '</form>';

  $con = mysqli_connect($theDb, $usr, $pass, "images");
  mysqli_select_db($con, "images");

  if (isset($_GET["page"])) {
   $page = $_GET["page"];
  } else {
   $page = 1;
  }

  $start_from = ($page - 1) * $selected;
  $query = "SELECT * FROM Greeting_Cards LIMIT $start_from, $selected";
  $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
  $images = array();

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $images[] = $row['image'];
   //store raw image
  }

  echo '<div id ="gallery">';

  foreach ($images as $image) {
   $origImage = $image;
   $image = WideImage::loadFromString($image) -> resize(250, 250);
   //image resizing here

   echo '<a href="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($origImage) . '"  data-lightbox="roadtrip"> <img id="database" class="fancybox" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($image) . '" /><a/>';
  }
  echo '</div>';

  $query = "SELECT COUNT(image) FROM Greeting_Cards";
  $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
  $total_images = $row[0];
  $total_pages = ceil($total_images / $selected);

  for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++) {
   echo "<a id='paginations' href='greetingcards.php?page=" . $i . "'>" . $i . "</a> ";
  }
```

Comment: Isn't it GET if you won't to "get" a variable value and POST for the form?

Comment: $_GET['$selected'] vs $_POST['displayAmount'] wich is it?

Comment: There are two sets where I use the get and posts. So the 1st set would be get and post, respectively; because you would want to see if $selected has been set to a number. If it has set it to the number from the form, so POST. The 2nd set would both be GET, with the same ideas, since $page is a variable.

Comment: probably makes sense to you - i have no idea what you're saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Q1 , I think you didn't set which option is selected as default.

For Q2 , it is also related to Q1, the selected is not set for option 10.

The following is an example code to solve Q1 and Q2:

```
//Check whether displayAmount is already selected, if no select 10 as default
 if (isset($_REQUEST['displayAmount'])) {
           $selected = $_REQUEST['displayAmount'];

       } else {
        $selected = 10;
    }

//Create array of display amount option for user to choose
$options = array(5,10,15,20);

 //create the form
 echo '<form method="post"><input type="button"  />
<select name="displayAmount"  onchange="this.form.submit();">';

//iterate through the option and set current option as selected.
 foreach ($options as $option) {
if($option == $selected){
    echo "<option selected='selected'> $option </option>";
}else{
    echo "<option> $option </option>";
}

}
echo '</select>';
```

For Q3: the pagination link mess up because the displayAmount is not included while creating the paging link, therefore your greetingcards.php is not receiving the latest displayAmount info.

The following is an example fix:

```
echo "<a id='paginations' href='greetingcards.php?page=" . $i . "&displayAmount=".$selected."'>" . $i . "</a> ";
```

Hope this help :)